# Oracle Forms 10g - communicating with hardware devices

Tags: java, oracleforms

Before `Oracle Forms 10g`, or `WebForms`, as the call it, functionality to communicate with hardware devices was done via `ActiveX` / `OCX` controls. As I undertand it, you now have to migrate this kind of functionality to either `Pluggable Java Component`'s (`PJC`s) or use `WebUtil` to be able to call `dll`'s on clients.

The problem is that information on this seems pretty scarce and based on this alone, it's difficult to choose a good way to communicate with a *hardware decive such as a scanner or a photo cam*. Has anyone done this and could indicate a either a tutorial, an example of such sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `PJC` to accomplish this.
There is a good site with examples from françois degrelle
[here](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/) and it also contains the code how to implement it.

If you use `PJC` then you are in java on the client side. So at that moment you can do anything you can do in java. Also communicate with devices.

You can also use jacob (JAva-COM Bridge), but I don't know this is suited for you.
But if it is [here](http://danadler.com/jacob/) is the main site about jacob with lots of explanation what you can do with it.

Comment: Why do you say client side since `WebForms` no longer supports client server architecture, but only web deployed apps? I'm a noob on any web issues and it's confusing for me.

Comment: Webforms is a 3 tier environment which means you got a client part (the java applet = frmall.jar) which runs on the client, an application server, which runs your forms process and a database to do all the queries. If you use a PJC, it is a jar file that is downloaded to the client and the applet makes a connection to it. So it runs on the client.

Comment: Do you know whether ActiveX controls will still work with Forms 10 (meaning they just don't handle bugs on this anymore) or not supporting it means the controls don't work at all?